# Checkboxes on visualforce aren't working

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, html

Everything was fine before i implemented html to this code. When i preview page i can't click on my checkboxes. Why?

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" sidebar="false" controller="DataLoadTestingClass">

<head>
<style>
a{                                        <!-- Ogólny display -->
display:block;
background:none;
padding: 10px;


}
div{
height:100vh;
width: 100%;
position:relative;

}
div:nth-child(2) {
background: url("http://www.myspacelayoutsupport.com/myspace-backgrounds/images/zapola.jpg") no-repeat center;
background-size: cover; 
}
dov:nth-child(3){
}
div:nth-child(4){
color:#008fd5;
font-size:1300%;
}

s1 {
font-size: 650%;
color:white;
} 
s10 {
font-size: 1000%;
color:yellow;
}
s11 {
font-size: 200%;                    <!-- Pierwsza strona -->
color:white;
}

p2{                                          <!-- Napis -->                  
font-size: 200%;                    
color:Black;
}

p20{                                                <!-- Zgoda dół -->        
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
}
the{
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:50%;
}
</style>
</head>

<apex:form>
 <body>

<div> 
<a id="one" >
<center>
        <s1>
        <font face="cursive">
        Życie pisze
        </font>
        </s1>
        <s10>
        scenariusze
        </s10><br/>
        <s11>
        Zostańmy w kontakcie!
        </s11>
 <a href="#two"><font color="White"><s> Przejdź dalej </s></font></a>
</center>
</a>
</div>

<div>
<a id="two">
<center>

        <p2>
        Zostańmy w kontakcie! 
        </p2>
        <table width="70%">
        <tr>  
        <th>Wyrażam zgodę na otrzymywanie drogą elektroniczną na wskazany przeze mnie adres e-mail informacji handlowej w rozumieniu art. 10 ust. 1 ustawy z dnia 18 lipca 2002 roku o świadczeniu usług drogą elektroniczną. </th>
        <th><apex:inputcheckbox value="{!bool1Val}" selected="true" styleClass="form-control" html-placeholder="Zgoda" required="false"/>
        </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>  
        <th>Wyrażam zgodę na otrzymywanie drogą telefoniczną na wskazany przeze mnie numer kontaktowy informacji handlowej. </th>
        <th><apex:inputcheckbox value="{!bool2Val}" selected="true" styleClass="form-control" html-placeholder="Zgoda" required="false"/>
        </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>  
        <th>Wyrażam dobrowolną zgodę na przetwarzanie moich danych osobowych, przekazanych przeze mnie lub za moją zgodą firmie.</th>
        <th><apex:inputcheckbox value="{!bool3Val}" styleClass="form-control" html-placeholder="Zgoda" required="false"/>
        </th>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <apex:commandButton value="WYŚLIJ" action="{!doInsert}" styleClass="buttonStyle" style="background:LightBlue;width:100px;height:40px;"/>

           <p20>
             Podane w formularzu dane osobowe będą przetwarzane przez  Services Sp. z o. o. z siedzibą<br/>
             <br/>
             o ochronie danych osobowych (Dz. U. z 2014., poz. 1182) w celach związanych z zgodami marketinogwymi.<br/>
             Podanie danych jest dobrowolne.
           </p20>
</center>
</a> 
</div>

<div> 
<a id="three">
<the style="background: -moz-radial-gradient(50% 50%, #808080, #fff); background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 50%, #808080, #fff); background: -o-radial-gradient(50% 50%, #808080, #fff); background: -ms-radial-gradient(50% 50%, #808080, #fff); background: radial-gradient(50% 50%, #808080, #fff)">
<center>Thank you!</center>
</the>
</a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
        }, 1800);
    });
</script>
</body>
</apex:form> 

</apex:page>
```

Checkboxes are unclickable.

[image]

Console shows that error after clicking on checkbox :

> DataLoadTestingPage12:136 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'top' of undefined
>
> ```
> at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (DataLoadTestingPage12:136)
> at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
> at HTMLDocument.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
> ```

Comment: Can you share a picture. Also can you check browser console for any errors?

Comment: Seems like :<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
        }, 1800);
    });
</script>  is a problem.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that code?  It looks like you are trying to get the string value of `href`'s offset, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: There is button which scrolls that page to section 'x' Something like this : https://devcorner.pl/przyklady/plynne-przewijanie/

Comment: w/e got this with different js : $(document).ready(function() { 
 
 $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
 
  var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );
 
  if( target.length ) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
   }, 1000);
  }
 });
 
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Everything was fine before i implemented html to this code."

The issue is that you set your checkboxes within an anchor tag

```
<a id="two">
checkbox1
checkbox2
checkbox3
</a>
```

and then in your script you are preventing the events triggered of whatever is within the anchor tags with:

prevent.default()

> Description: If this method is called, the default action of the event
> will not be triggered.

[jquery's api documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

in other words, this behavior is expected =P

you can test by removing the anchortag that wraps your checkboxes or removing the prevent.default() method

Szczęśliwy kodowanie!